# RewriteCond to get THE_REQUEST of homepage

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have these directives in my `.htaccess` to not cache the page for some urls:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (compile|chat|another-page) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [NC,E=HEADER_NOCACHE:true]
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</IfModule>
```

It works like a charm for the pages `h..ps://my-url/compile`, `h..ps://my-url/chat` and `h..ps://my-url/another-page`

I need to add the same rule for the homepage, that should be (I am not sure if there is the `/` at the end) just:
`h..ps://my-url`

What should I add to the first cond? Something like?

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (compile|chat|another-page|/) [NC]
```

Comment: Do you need to use `THE_REQUEST`?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific reason, `THE_REQUEST` is not the natural variable to use here (but there are other ways around that as well).

`THE_REQUEST` contains the first line of the request headers, it doesn't simply contain the URL-path, which is what you are trying to match against. It is a string of the form:

```
GET /compile HTTP/1.1
```

So, a single slash is present in every URL - at the start of the URL-path.

You need to be more specific in your regex (eg. using anchors) to differentiate `/` from `/compile`. In your current condition, you are matching `compile` anywhere in the requested URL (including the query string), so you could potentially override the cache by simple appending `?compile` to *any* URL.

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the URL-path only. However, you don't need any condition here, since the `RewriteRule` *pattern* also matches against the URL-path only (less the slash prefix).

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(compile|chat|another-page)?$ - [NC,E=HEADER_NOCACHE:true]
```

With start and end-of-string anchors, the whole pattern is made optional so it matches an empty URL-path (ie. the root) as well. Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash.

However, you don't even need to use mod_rewrite. The simpler `SetEnvIf` (mod_setenvif) or `SetEnvIfNoCase` (if you specifically need a case-insensitive match) would do the job and would be the preferred choice here. For example:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/(compile|chat|another-page)?$" HEADER_NOCACHE=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just use a simple [expression block](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) (available in Apache 2.4 or later):

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/(compile|chat|another-page)?$#">
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</If>
```

Comment: what about the homepage?

Comment: `?` after closing `)` makes whole group optional so it will match for home page also.

Comment: If you using 2.4+ version then this is preferred way of doing things instead of old tricks.